# PyCharm virtualenv won't find correct python binaries

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, virtualenv

When setting up a virtualenv in PyCharm I noticed that it uses Python 3.5 even though in my /usr/bin directory there are only Python 3.6 binaries. When setting up another virtualenv and searching for the binaries I realized that when searching through the /usr/bin folder in the PyCharm dialog the contents were different to the actual contents (at least compared to what I am seeing in console/file manager).

I haven't found a reason nor a solution to this problem.

Comment: Others cannot see what you saw unless you provide a screenshot of the mentioned dialog and a directory listing.
If it is the way you described, run `ls -la venv/bin/`, then maybe file a bug.

Comment: I have found the reason: pycharm, when installed through the package manager, is deployed with flatpak, which generates a virtual environment.